# Trying to recode a column based on whether or not it contains a certain string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to generalize on groups and I have a column of string titles in a dataframe. I want to split them based on whether or not they contain a string. There are many groups but they all either contain the string `"Alpha"` `"Beta"` or `"Gamma"`. I would like to recode a new column with those titles. The function below doesn't seem to work in the way I intended and I am not sure whether a regex or `np.where` approach would be better. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
def recode_func(n):
    for i in n:
        if "Alpha" in i:
            i == "Alpha"
        elif "Beta" in i:
            i== "Beta"
        elif "Gamma" in i:
            i == "Gamma"
        else:
            continue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to iterate a list and use [`pd.Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
for item in ['Alpha', 'Beta', 'Gamma']:
    df.loc[df['col'].str.contains(item, regex=False), 'col'] = item
```

As above, `regex=False` should improve performance.

This will be more efficient than iterating your dataframe by row.